# OrientDB - LET variable in where

Tags: where-clause, orientdb, let

I have a query very similar to this:

```
SELECT FROM Post 
LET 
$category = (SELECT EXPAND(out('PartOf')) FROM $current),
$poster = (SELECT EXPAND(in('Posted')) FROM $current) 
WHERE 
$poster <> #18:1
AND $poster IN (SELECT EXPAND(out('IsUser')) FROM (SELECT EXPAND(out('Related')) FROM #18:1) WHERE out('RelatedIn') IN ($category))
LIMIT 10000
```

And a graph like this:

```
CREATE CLASS Post EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS Category EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS User EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS UserRelated EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS PartOf EXTENDS E;
CREATE CLASS IsUser EXTENDS E;
CREATE CLASS Posted EXTENDS E;
CREATE CLASS Related EXTENDS E;
CREATE CLASS RelatedIn EXTENDS E;

PartOf relates Post and Cateogry
IsUser relates UserRelated and User
Posted relates User and Post
Related relates User and UserRelated
RelatedIn relates UserRelated and Category

UserRelated is an hyper-edge
```

What I'm looking for are posts, from users related to another user (#18:1), where the relation between the users is in the same category as the category of the post the query is traversing at that moment.

The where clause after the AND does not work. If I remove it, the query gives the same results.

On the other side, if I change $category in that clause with a specific @rid, the query works perfectly... but I need more than one specific category.

So, what is wrong with this query?

(I hope this explanation is clear enough)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $category cannot be accessed from the where. I really don't know why.
But I solved it using another varaible:

```
SELECT FROM Post 
LET 
$category = (SELECT EXPAND(out('PartOf')) FROM $current),
$poster = (SELECT EXPAND(in('Posted')) FROM $current),
$relatedUser = (SELECT EXPAND(out('IsUser')) FROM (SELECT EXPAND(out('Related')) FROM #18:1) WHERE out('RelatedIn') IN ($parent.category))
WHERE 
$poster <> #18:1
AND $poster IN ($relatedUser)
LIMIT 10000
```

The key was using $parent.category inside the subquery. It was not so clear to me that a declared variable in the parent should be used with $parent.variable in any subqueries.

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: What is the purpose of this operator ?
<>

Comment: '<>' operator means not equal ;)